# How to show Linux mass storage gadget connection speed?

Tags: linux, embedded, usb, usb-mass-storage

I have a serial console shell connected to the Device and loaded the mass storage gadget driver and have a USB connection from the Linux Device to a PC host and I want to print the connection speed from the Device shell.

Is there a way to show from a serial console shell prompt the connection speed on the device side of a mass storage gadget connection other than the dmesg from the driver?

Comment: Would it be possible to transfer a fixed amount of data and benchmark it? Then maybe do it multiple times to average the randomness introduced by the OS scheduler (even though if it's DMA based it should be consistent)

Comment: @Fra93, USB is always DMA based.

Comment: @0andriy good to know, than it should hide the OS interference and show the actual link speed.

Comment: Have you checked sysfs for that? Or do you want to know *effective* speed?

Comment: @0andriy I have not checked sysfs. Where is it in sysfs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 0andriy, I found that the current speed is available in sysfs. On my system it was here:

```
root@dra7xx-evm:~# cat /sys/devices/platform/44000000.ocp/48880000.omap_dwc3_1/48890000.usb/udc/48890000.usb/current_speed
super-speed
```